# Google Maps postcode plotting in the wrong place?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

Im trying to pull data from my table and plot it on google maps.

Im using the following that works...

```
function addPostCode(zip) {
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zip}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                name: zip
            });
            markers.push(marker);
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
            });
        }
```

Only if my postcode is LA14 for example it plots this as a road in germany called la14, as opposed to barrow in furness in the UK, doesn anybody have any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing ambiguous information. Same thing would occur if you pass 'London', trying  to get 'London, Canada' as opposed to the more popular 'London, United Kingdom'.

**Option 1 - If all your postal codes are in the UK**:

You can change `{ 'address': zip}` to `{ 'address': zip + ', United Kingdom'}`. This just specifies that the zip codes are in the UK. Comma is optional.

**Option 2 - If only some are in the UK**:

You can add an optional `country` parameter to the function, then pass 'United Kingdom' to it for the ambiguous cases:

```
function addPostCode(zip, country) {

    var address;

    if (typeof(country) === 'undefined')  // no country passed
        address = zip;
    else
        address = zip + ', ' + country;

    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
...
```

I'd go with Option 2, even if your values are UK-only, just in case you internationalize it later.